# Android spinner clickable doesn't work in Lollipop and higher

Tags: android, xamarin, spinner

In the spinners in my xamarin Android project I want to set clickable to false but still detect clicks via an OnTouchListener. This is so I can suppress the list of items appearing unless the user clicks on a specific part of the spinner view.
This approach works perfectly in KitKat and lower, but in Lollipop and higher the clickable setting seems to have no effect and the spinner always shows the list of items when clicked.
Does anyone know how I can get a spinner in Lollipop and later to not show the list of items when clicked but still respond to click events?

Below is the code from my test project.

Layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<Spinner android:id="@+id/testSpinner"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginBottom ="10sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.testSpinner);


        List<string> items = new List<string>() { "Dave", "Ben", "Dan" };

        spinner.Clickable = false;

        ConnectArrayAdapter adapter = new ConnectArrayAdapter(this, spinner, items);
        spinner.Adapter = adapter;

    }
}
```

Relevant bits of code from the array adapter (I  only want the items to appear when the user clicks on an image in the view):

```
  public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = base.GetView(position, convertView, parent);

        TextView textView = (TextView)view;

        textView.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
        textView.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 16);
        textView.Gravity = TextGravity;

        textView.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, m_image, null);

        textView.SetOnTouchListener(new SelectImageTouchListener(textView, m_parent));
        m_parent.Clickable = false;

        return view;
    }

    private class SelectImageTouchListener : RightDrawableOnTouchListener
    {
        private Spinner m_spinner;
        public SelectImageTouchListener(TextView view, Spinner spinner) : base(view)
        {
            m_spinner = spinner;
        }

        public override bool OnDrawableTouch(MotionEvent e)
        {
            m_spinner.PerformClick();

            e.Action = MotionEventActions.Cancel;
            return false;
        }
    }

 public abstract class RightDrawableOnTouchListener : Java.Lang.Object,   View.IOnTouchListener
{
    private Drawable m_drawable;
    private int m_fuzz = 10;

    public RightDrawableOnTouchListener(TextView view) : base()
    {
        List<Drawable> drawables = view.GetCompoundDrawables().ToList();
        if (drawables != null && drawables.Count == 4)
            m_drawable = drawables[2];
    }

    public new IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Handle;
        }
    }

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down && m_drawable != null)
        {
            int x = (int)e.GetX();
            int y = (int)e.GetY();
            Rect bounds = m_drawable.Bounds;

            if (x >= (v.Right - bounds.Width() - m_fuzz) && x <= (v.Right - v.PaddingRight + m_fuzz)
                && y >= (v.PaddingTop - m_fuzz) && y <= (v.Height - v.PaddingBottom) + m_fuzz)
            {
                return OnDrawableTouch(e);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public abstract bool OnDrawableTouch(MotionEvent e);
}
```

Comment: Add => android:enabled=false

Comment: But then it doesn't respond to any click events at all!

Comment: Could you share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem or post the complete codes of your adapter?

Comment: @Elvis please go to https://www.dropbox.com/s/5caz8donjyqh0aw/TestSpinnerWithImage.7z?dl=0 for a demo